# What is the purpose of the /cdrom directory in Ubuntu-based Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

A quick one... I noticed this folder in `/` on Kubuntu 15.10:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 12 02:33 cdrom
```

Why is it there and how is it used? Shouldn't CD-ROMs be (auto-)mounted in `/media` by udisks2 (or manually wherever I want them)? My current system doesn't have an optical drive, so I can't test this for myself. I just came across it while identifying folders in `/` to exclude in my rsync script.

Comment: /cdrom is used for read-only chroot/Live-DVD/pendrive ISO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's there since ancient times and probably for various compatibility reasons.

Some explanation from [CD-ROMs subchapter](http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_31.html#SEC426) of The Linux Cookbook follows here:

> Like the `/floppy` directory, the use of the `/cdrom` directory is a standard practice and convenient, but not necessary -- you can mount disks in whatever empty directory you like. (You could even, for example, mount discs from the CD-ROM drive to `/floppy` and mount floppy disks to `/cdrom`, but why would anyone do that!)

Also, I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/13706/37165) on Ask Ubuntu that has the ultimate answer to your question:

> While `/mnt/` and `/media/` are common places to mount devices, the device location can be just about anywhere. `/cdrom/` was probably chosen for either brevity or legacy support.

Comment: While this doesn't explain how `/cdrom` is used in modern distros, kudos for digging up that link. Searching for "/cdrom" on Google or the StackExchange sites is an excercise in futility...

Comment: Commenting on the edit: very nice find! I googled for quite a while but failed to discover that one. The comments are pretty funny ("folder sometimes turns into a link") but I think it's safe to say that `/cdrom` has been kept as a legacy mount point, and can be ignored by most users of recent distributions. I guess, in time, it will just go where `/floppy` went :)

Comment: Much like the media themselves; `/cdrom` is as used as `/floppy`.  `sudo rmdir /cdrom` to allow single char autocomplete on softlink `/code`.  (Tested after digging through attic to find a CD-ROM, found a USB floppy drive - curious to know if install on a machine with an **IDE** floppy would yield `/floppy`)